# DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: Fragment merge failure

Tags: java, websphere

We have a war file that uses java, spring etc. I am trying to deploy this war file in Websphere 9. I had setup datasource. I am getting the following weird error when I try to deploy the war file. I am not getting much info on internet about the error. Any one has any idea?
The same war is working fine in JBOSS and web.xml file looks fine.

ErrorThe EAR file could be corrupt and/or incomplete. Make sure that the application is at a compatible Java(TM) Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) level for the current version of WebSphere(R) Application Server.
com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: Fragment merge failure [Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: Fragment merge failure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some problem with one custom dependency in the pom file that resulted the above error. Removing that dependency fixed the issue in my case. Check the log file for more info on the dependency that is causing the issue, identify the culprit and remove it from the pom file.